# Headless debian: Issues connecting to wifi

Tags: debian, networking, raspberry-pi, network-interface, dhcp

I am trying to set up wifi with this [image](https://raspi.debian.net/) on my raspberry pi 4b. I have previously done this with Raspi OS image. However this seems to much harder. Recommendation is to use `/etc/network/interfaces.d/wlan0` (cf. [second point in the FAQ](https://raspi.debian.net/faq/)). I have previously used wpa_supplicant.conf. My /etc/network/interfaces.d/wlan0 looks like this:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
#iface wlan0 inet6 dhcp
address 192.168.0.14
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
    wpa-ssid 'some wifi name'
    wpa-bssid 'S0:M3:M4:C0:A6:R3'
    wpa-psk '\'password\'withquotes'
```

Note that I use the `bssid`, because I have a wifi router and an access point within my reach. Both have the same name. With static IP I get an internal IP but it seems I am just assigning an IP to myself and that is it. Any `ping` request cant find the host, even when I ping my gateway.

I also tried using DHCP. I commented the address, gateway as well as the netmask attribute and then used `iface wlan0 inet dhcp`. Result was "No DHCPOFFERS received".

EDIT Friday 7 January 2022:

When I type `ifup wlan0` with `dhcp` in `interfaces.d/wlan0` enabled, I get:

```
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Listening on LPF/wlan0/S0:M3:M4:C0:A6:R3
Sending on LPF/wlan0/S0:M3:M4:C0:A6:R3
Sending on Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
No DHCPOFFERS received.
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
upa_supplicant: /sbin/upa_supplicant daemon failed to start
run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
ifup: failed to bring up wlan0
```

I even created another wifi network with no spaces and simple but long password. Same message as before. I also tried to create a `wpa_supplicant.conf` and tried connecting with it. It successfully initiates the wpa_supplicant service - but that is it. No network connectivity. I had done this before on Rasperry OS (Raspbian Buster).

Maybe important. I do not have `dhcpd` with this debian image but `dhclient`. However I do not see how that influences things.

Comment: Scanning for wifi networks is not problem with `iw wlan0 scan` works - but `iw wlan0 link' returns simply "Not connected"

Comment: firstly, don't use `'` to enclose the values of `wpa-*`, secondly, use `wpa_passphrase` to create the correct value for `wpa-psk` - as [documented](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse#wpa_supplicant) - `I have previously used wpa_supplicant.conf` why "previously" ... you need to use it "currently"

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I added an edit to the question to make more clear. Either way I am quite sure I will abandon this image and use the stock Raspberry OS Image instead. No use if I have that much trouble configuring wifi